# laravel intervention image size is wrong

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to upload image from android device and want to compress it, but the result of image size is different from real

1st case : original file on android is 1.94MB, and I use this code to upload original size but after upload my photo sizse only 1.060 KB (see in pict)

```
$image = $request->file('tes');
$extension = '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$imageName = rand(1, 9999) . time() . date('YmdHis') .'.jpg';
$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
$img->orientate(); //so that the photo does not rotate automatically
$destinationPath = public_path("images/tes");
$img->save($destinationPath . '/' . $imageName);
```

2nd case : original file on android is 1.94MB, and I want to compress it to 50% (what I expected if calculate from original file on android is more or less 952KB, but the result is wrong like the pict). here's the code

```
$image = $request->file('tes');
$extension = '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$imageName = rand(1, 9999) . time() . date('YmdHis') .'.jpg';
$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
$img->orientate(); //so that the photo does not rotate automatically
$destinationPath = public_path("images/tes");
$img->save($destinationPath . '/' . $imageName, 100); // I tried to change to 99%, 50% and the result like the pict
```

so why intervention image is compressed the file when I want the original size like 1st case. and why if I tried to have 100% quality even got a bigger size, and get wrong size from original in another quality size like 2nd case ?
Shouldn't the results without compression and 100% quality produce the same size as the original photo?

[image: pict]

Comment: Where in your code are you 'compressing' and not compressing your image?

Answer (score 0):

When you set no value to `$img-save()` it uses the [default value of 90](https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/save).

```php
$img->save($destinationPath . '/' . $imageName);

// is actually

$img->save($destinationPath . '/' . $imageName, 90);
```

That an image size increases with a high quality setting is expected as the the jpeg FAQ states:

> Except for experimental purposes, never go above about Q 95; using Q 100
> will produce a file two or three times as large as Q 95, but of hardly any
> better quality.  Q 100 is a mathematical limit rather than a useful setting.

Additional infos - sources:

FAQ JPEG - [What are good "quality" settings for JPEG](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-5.html)

Github Issue [#632 - File size increases almost 300%](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/632) -
imho no Bug but comments give an insight